RuntimeError: stack expects each tensor to be equal size, but got [400, 400] at entry 0 and [400, 400, 4] at entry 6
I am working on image segmentation with a breast cancer dataset. This is the sample of the image and the mask.


# I have a data frame which contains paths to the input image and the mask.

# 0 benign/benign (174).png benign/benign (174)_mask.png    0
# 1 benign/benign (385).png benign/benign (385)_mask.png    0

# This is my data set class
class MyDataloader(torch.utils.data.Dataset):

  def __init__( self, df, dir_path ):

    self.df = df
    self.dir_path = dir_path

  def __len__(self):
    return len(self.df)

  def __getitem__(self, idx):

    cur_index = self.df.iloc[idx]
    # print(cur_index[0])
    # print(cur_index[1],'\n')

    img_path = os.path.join( self.dir_path,  cur_index[0] )  ## image path
    gt_path  = os.path.join( self.dir_path,  cur_index[1] )  ## gt path
    # print(img_path)
    # print(gt_path, '\n')

    img = Image.open(img_path)
    gt  = Image.open(gt_path)

    # Convert the image and gt to a NumPy array
    img = np.array(img)
    gt  = np.array(gt).astype(np.float32)
    # print(img.shape, ' ---- ', img.dtype)
    # print(gt.shape,  ' ---- ', gt.dtype)

    # define transform
    transform = A.Compose([
                A.Resize(height=400, width=400),
                A.RandomRotate90(),
                A.Transpose(),
                A.ShiftScaleRotate(shift_limit=0.0625, scale_limit=0.50, rotate_limit=45, p=.75),
                A.Blur(blur_limit=3),
                A.OpticalDistortion(),
                A.GridDistortion(),
                A.HueSaturationValue()
                # A.Normalize( mean = (0.485, 0.456, 0.406), std = (0.229, 0.224, 0.225) )
                ])
    # print('after transform')
    # apply transform
    augmented       = transform( image = img, mask = gt )
    augmented_image = augmented['image']
    augmented_gt    = augmented['mask']

    augmented_image = torch.tensor(augmented_image).permute(2, 0, 1).float()
    augmented_gt    = torch.tensor(augmented_gt)


    return augmented_image, augmented_gt


# This is the split function:

def train_val_test_split_func( df ):
  # Shuffle the list to ensure random splits
  # random.shuffle(data)

  # Calculate split indices
  length = len(df)
  split1 = int(0.6 * length)
  split2 = int(0.8 * length)

  # Split the list
  train = df.iloc[ :split1]
  val   = df.iloc[ split1:split2]
  test  = df.iloc[ split2:]

  return train, val, test


# Splitting the df in the train, validation and split.

train_df, val_df, test_df = train_val_test_split_func( df_paths )
train_ds = MyDataloader( train_df, base_path )
val_ds =  MyDataloader( val_df, base_path )
test_ds = MyDataloader( test_df, base_path )

# CREATE DATALOADERS FOR PARALLEL DATA LOADING

batch_size = 20

# create train dataloader --
train_dl = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(
    train_ds,
    batch_size = batch_size,
    drop_last = True,
    shuffle = True,
    num_workers = 4
)
# create validation dataloader
val_dl = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(
    val_ds,
    batch_size = batch_size,
    drop_last = False,  # False
    shuffle = False,
    num_workers = 4
)

# The following code is throwing the error

i = 0
for data in train_dl:
  i += 1
  print('-----------------------------------',i)
  inp, gt = data
  print(inp.shape)
  print(gt.shape) 
# Error:

RuntimeError: stack expects each tensor to be equal size, but got [400, 400] at entry 0 and [400, 400, 4] at entry 6

Since the error suggest there is something wrong with the shapes of the images or masks, I tried to print the shapes of the input and mask right before the transformation, and the shapes looked fine. I don't understand why I am getting the shapes error.
